# How can I install laravel 8 project in windows PC?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am facing a problem in installing laravel 8 projects. I have already a composer but still can not install the project on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try by using the following command:

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name

Answer (score 0):

1> install composer

2> install laravel - composer global require laravel/installer

3> Create Project - laravel new blog

4> This command will start a development server -  PHP artisan serve

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#installation-via-composer

Comment: Thanks, but I have already found the solution.